# AndroidManifest.xml:100: error: ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-keystore

Wheni try to uplod into playstore my working apk after signing am  getting below error in playstore console

AndroidManifest.xml:100: error: ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value

Upload failed
Your APK cannot be analyzed using aapt. Error output:
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
AndroidManifest.xml:100: error: ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute is not a string value

can some one assist on this why am getting this error 
 Below Is my app manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:aandroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="com.KryptosTextApp.KryptosText">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.ChatApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        >

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCSplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="KryptosText"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name=".activity.PHCChatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCMediaSliderActivity"

            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCMessageInfo"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCCreateGroupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCSelectMembersForGroupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.GroupInfoActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCGroupInfoActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ComposeMessageActivity"
            android:label="@null"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCSelectGroupActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCNotificationViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PHCVedioPlayActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TermsPrivacyWebViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainDrawerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.VerifyOTPActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verify_otp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ResetUpdatePasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_update_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TermsAndCondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_terms_and_cond"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CreateMPin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_mpin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <service android:name=".serviceManager.PHCChatService" />
        />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SecurityQuestionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_security_questions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.EnterMpinActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ChangeProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ChangeMPinActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_mpin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ResetMPinActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_mpin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DriveAcivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drive_acivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DriveMediaTabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drive_media_tabbed"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FingerprintAuthenticationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fingerprint_authentication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.UserManualActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_manual"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DriveDocsTabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drive_docs_tabbed"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />


        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MediaDocWebView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <!-- Autobahn demo sample activities -->
        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.EchoClientActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.TestSuiteClientActivity" />


        <!--
         Defining Services
     -->
        <service android:name=".serviceManager.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".serviceManager.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

       <!-- <receiver android:name=".receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                &lt;!&ndash;
                                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                &ndash;&gt;
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <receiver android:name=".serviceManager.PHCServiceReceiver" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: share your manifest file code

Comment: tools:replace="android:label" remove this line

Comment: I have another library project module so if I remove that I will get build failed error

Comment: android:label="@null" , remove @null.

Comment: Seems that the issue thanks a lot I did not delete on overlook